# Magento2: How to add custom mass action with pop up though UI

Tags: magento2, modal-popup

I need to add custom mass action , but when you click on mass action option i need one pop up instead of redirecting to action url

that is custom js for my custom mass action

can any one help me on that

Comment: What kind of popup? You want a popup with an information only what is going to happen or with some kind of a form prior to the action itself?

Comment: I would like to apply a pop-up before the action itself, I have an add button I want to choose the category before applying the add

Comment: I used ui-component